# express crashes if req.file is undefined

Tags: express, next.js, multer

when making a post request to an express api without an attached file in the request, the api crashes and provides the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')` error. However i would like to make it so the api does not crash when a post request is made without an attached image. any ideas ?

express code :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, res, cb) => {
        cb(null, dir)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const members = await Member.find();
        res.json(members);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
})
router.get('/:id', getMember, async (req, res) => {
    res.json(res.member)
})
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) =>{
    const member = new Member({
        name: req.body.name,
        occupation: req.body.occupation,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        join: req.body.join,
        image: req.file.filename
    })
    try {
        const newMember = await member.save()
        res.status(201).json(newMember)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }
})
```

nextjs code to actually send the file:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
            const formDatas = new FormData()
            formDatas.append('name', name)
            formDatas.append('occupation', occupation)
            formDatas.append('bio', paragraph)
            formDatas.append('join', date)
            formDatas.append('image', img)
        console.log(formDatas)
        axios
        .post(api + '/members', formDatas)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: You could move that `const member = …` into your try, that way your catch would catch if the file is missing. If you want it to continue if no file is provided then you can do as suggested in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurred because you're trying to access object of undefined variable req.file;

You can make changes according to your need

1 If you don't want to accept request without any file

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
if (!req.file) { //or you can check if(req.file===undefiend)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Please attach a file' });
}
const member = new Member({
    name: req.body.name,
    occupation: req.body.occupation,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    join: req.body.join,
    image: req.file.filename
})
try {
    const newMember = await member.save()
    res.status(201).json(newMember)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
}
```

})

2 If you want to store null/empty string (in case of no file upload)

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
const member = new Member({
    name: req.body.name,
    occupation: req.body.occupation,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    join: req.body.join,
    image: req.file!==undefined ? req.file.filename : null
})
try {
    const newMember = await member.save()
    res.status(201).json(newMember)
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Change as shown below

```js
 const member = new Member({
        name: req.body.name,
        occupation: req.body.occupation,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        join: req.body.join,
        image: req.file.filename ? req.file.filename : ""
    })
```

This should stop crashing but until I see the whole code wont know how you are handling error

Comment: hi!! unfortunately it still returns an error :(